# Does sharing a connection with a chromebook make my desktop insecure

Tags: security, chromebook

I have two computers, a desktop running ubuntu and a chromebook. The chromebook requires apps to function, which state that they have the right to read and change anything. I am considering getting a vpn for the desktop, but since they share a connection, is the desktop insecure no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

Even though your Ubuntu machine and your Chrome book are on the same local network, the Chromebook (and the apps on it) cannot access anything on your Ubuntu machine, unless you've specifically made things available from the Ubuntu machine.  For example, unless you've set up NFS (or similar) on the Ubuntu machine, none of the drives or their contents can be read from the Chromebook.
The bottom line is, unless you've explicitly said to your Ubuntu machine, "Go ahead and let others see this or that," the data on your Ubuntu machine is safe from the apps you've installed on your Chromebook.